# Google Places API how to get additional search result

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am using Google Places API Web Service with [Text Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=en#TextSearchRequests).

I found there that

> [each search can return as many as 60 results, split across three pages](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=en#PlaceSearchPaging)

My issue is, I am requesting for phrase e.g 'plumber in new york' which url like

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=plumber+in+new+york&key=GOOGLE_API_KEY

This will return me a result with 20 records also with [next_page_token](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=en#PlaceSearchPaging), but when I making another request using this token than it must have to give me another 'next_page_token' for get the third page as to get the last 20 results.

> But this second page didn't returning with 'next_page_token', which
>   meant that there is only 40 results. But in [Google Map search 'Plumber in new york'](https://www.google.co.in/maps/search/plumber+in+new+york/@40.8078805,-74.0087382,12z/data=!3m1!4b1) has results even more than 60.

I want to get all the result like [Google Map Search shows](https://www.google.co.in/maps/search/plumber+in+new+york/@40.8078805,-74.0087382,12z/data=!3m1!4b1), how can i get that? Please guide.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A maximum of 60 results are available through the Places API text search for a given location/query, there is no way to "work around" that.

Comment: geocodezip: they aren't asking how to work around the 60 result limit, they're asking why this query only gets 40 results, which appears to be a bug.

Comment: This looks like a bug, it does seem like you should get more than 40 results for that query.  Please file it at http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Bug, we'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you for study this issue. I will raise this issue to google as spiv you suggested, and will also let know here when it get resolve.

Comment: I believe this is fixed now.